# Cannot replicate md5 encoded string with CryptoJs

Tags: javascript, md5, cryptojs

I want to play with a Rest API. This requires the creation of an X-Auth key for authentication.

The documentation said:

> The X-Auth-Key header should be constructed using the following
> algorithm: md5(api_key + md5(url + X-Auth-User + api_key +
> X-Auth-Expires)).
>
> For example, consider a GET request to
> https://<server_ip>/api/live_events/1?clean=true by the user 'admin'
> with the api_key '1acpJN7oEDn3BDDYhQ' that expires on June 1, 2011
> UTC. In this case the url parameter is '/live_events/1' and the
> X-Auth-Expires value is '1306886400'. Thus the value of X-Auth-Key
> should be computed as follows:
>
> md5('1acpJN7oEDn3BDDYhQ' +
> md5('/live_events/1'+'admin'+'1acpJN7oEDn3BDDYhQ'+'1306886400'))
> => md5('1acpJN7oEDn3BDDYhQ' + md5('/live_events/1admin1acpJN7oEDn3BDDYhQ1306886400'))
> => '**180c88df8d0d4182385f6eb7e7045a42**'

I have tried to implement this with [cryptojs](/questions/tagged/cryptojs), but unfortunately I can't get the values of the example:

```
<script>
var md5xx =  CryptoJS.MD5('/live_events/1admin1acpJN7oEDn3BDDYhQ1306886400')
var md5yy = CryptoJS.MD5(('1acpJN7oEDn3BDDYhQ') + String(md5xx));
console.log(md5yy.toString());
// => 17222238c238b7ac9f76ea8d0fe1e330
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The md5 hash you obtained `17222238c238b7ac9f76ea8d0fe1e330` is correct.
The given `180c88df8d0d4182385f6eb7e7045a42` example with reverse lookup gives a different link `/jobs/1admin1acpJN7oEDn3BDDYhQ1306886400` instead of `/live_events/1admin1acpJN7oEDn3BDDYhQ1306886400`.
You can cross check with
https://md5.gromweb.com/?md5=180c88df8d0d4182385f6eb7e7045a42
and
https://md5.gromweb.com/?md5=a39ee4e3aa79939249cb6b5e7faead28

```js
//the hash you actually expected
var md5xx =  CryptoJS.MD5('/jobs/1admin1acpJN7oEDn3BDDYhQ1306886400')
var md5yy = CryptoJS.MD5(('1acpJN7oEDn3BDDYhQ') + String(md5xx));
console.log(md5yy.toString());

//correct hash according to the given link
var md5xx =  CryptoJS.MD5('/live_events/1admin1acpJN7oEDn3BDDYhQ1306886400')
var md5yy = CryptoJS.MD5(('1acpJN7oEDn3BDDYhQ') + String(md5xx));
console.log(md5yy.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```